# Dynamic Controls and Postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a Panel. Now in that panel, i'm adding controls. It is getting added and displayed.The problem is when the page is posted back.I know the controls have to be binded again in the panel. But lets say if the user has entered some value in the dynamic created text box. Its is getting lost..

Comment: some sample code? u have you make sure the "viewstate" works?

Answer (score 3):

I have done this before by storing the data from the controls in session.

Every time you dynamically add a control, store the current data entered into the controls in session or viewstate for example, and then rebind on postback. Not the most elegant solution but it worked. I take it this is a webforms question?

1. Add dynamic control click
2. Save current form data
3. On page_load load the data from viewstate into the controls

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the controls get the **same ID** each time (for ex. by specifying an ID explicitly)
and you should add the dynamic controls on **Page.Init** so they can participate in the page's life-cycle.

There's an article on 4guysfromrolla.com, [Dynamic Web Controls, Postbacks, and View State](https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx)

Comment: If you have to add controls in Page.Init; how can you add controls in response to events, which are processed after Page.Init?