# LinkButton Click event not firing after programatic hookup

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, event-hooking

I am creating linkbuttons inside of a panel and hooking up an event handler to the Click event.  It isn't firing.  This is my code.  Is this lost on postback?

```
            foreach (var item in clients)
            {
                var codeLb = new LinkButton() { Text = item.CLIENT_CODE, CssClass = "codeColumn", CommandArgument = item.CLIENT_CODE, CommandName = "Select" };
                codeLb.Click += ResultsLinkButton_Click;
                ResultsPanel.Controls.Add(codeLb);

                var nameLb = new LinkButton() { Text = item.CLIENT_NAME, CssClass = "nameColumn", CommandArgument = item.CLIENT_CODE, CommandName = "Select" };
                nameLb.Click += ResultsLinkButton_Click;
                ResultsPanel.Controls.Add(nameLb);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes every dynamically created controls are lost on after postback.

You need to recreate them again on postback and again hook up the Event Handler.

You can read more

https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx

[Dynamic Controls and Postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430982/dynamic-controls-and-postback)

Hope it helps.